Routing rules for npm Nexus proxy repo
I want to use a Nexus repo as a proxy for my npmjs.org requests when I do "npm i", where I explicitly can specify what packages I want to allow.
So I'm trying to set up routing rules for that purpose.
E.g. for the package zone.js I see in outbound-request.log, that there are two requests.
The first one is:
https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js
And the second:
https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js/-/zone.js-0.13.3.tgz
The following matcher in the routing rules is too restrictive, so that zone.js is not installed:
.*\/zone.js-0.13.*

But if I change the matcher to:
.*\/zone.js.*

both requests pass through.
I'm afraid, it's just the way how packages are fetched from npmjs.org, meaning the first request is just the package name, and the second request contains the version info.
Or is there a possibility to make the rules more restrictive?
I use Sonatype Nexus Repository OSS 3.63.0-01
Any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated.

I'm very curious about your goal. npm is famous for having large dependency trees. Is manually allow-listing specific components really the way to go? What process are you using to decide that a given component is okay to add to the list?

Thank you for your comment @Michael Prescott.
The idea is to have an extra layer of control and awareness.
Admittedly, in the first step I would extract the info what versions of packages I need from the package-lock.json and generate the matchers for the routing rule.
Should it turn out that a package is malicious, I would block it in the routing rule.
Should another package in the dependency tree also depend on that malicious package, I would at least notice it and decide from there on what to do.

Right - that makes sense as an experiment, a bit like programming in assembly. What we normally see is that the process has to scale to much higher frequencies of dependency updates than an in-house team can manage, at least not without a terrible slowdown on the engineering teams. Appsec and dev speed can be in direct opposition unless you have automation and a good data feed. (There are >1000 of new malicious components in the npm ecosystem every month.)

Using these two matchers works for my purpose:
.*/zone.js
.*/zone.js/-/zone.js-0.13.3.tgz 
So, the solution for me is to generate two matchers for every package. 
This one:  .*/zone.js  is to make the call to "https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js" work.
And this one  .*/zone.js/-/zone.js-0.13.3.tgz  is to make the calls to  https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js/-/zone.js-0.13.3.tgz  and  https://my-nexus-deployment-url/zone.js/-/zone.js-0.13.3.tgz  work.
